# Best way to use variable across functions in python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, cgpdfdocument

I need to refer to the same variable in several functions in a python script. (The write context of a CGPDFDocument).

I can either write `global writeContext` in every function;

or add the variable as an argument to every function;

....both of which seem to be excessive duplication.

Other answers to questions about global variables in python suggest that they are "bad".
So what's the better way of handling it?

Comment: Sounds like you want to define a class

Comment: The question is, is this variable going to be modified inside any function?

Comment: Ah: you're right. I only need to use global in the one function where it is modified. Doh.